# Type hierarchy missing members contributed by aspects

Tags: eclipse, aspectj

When I open the Quick Type Hierarchy popup (ctrl+t) on an interface method, it doesn't include any mention of implementation methods that are contributed by aspects. What can I do to make these show up?

For example, consider the following interface, classes and aspect:

*Interface:*

```
public interface Editable {
    void save()
}
```

*Class Implementing `Editable#save` directly:*

```
public class EditableItem implements Editable {
    public void save() {
        // do some saving
    }
}
```

*Another class, this time without direct implementation of `Editable`'s `save`:*

```
public class EditableModule implements Editable {
    // o-oh.. not implemented here
}
```

*But this aspect adds `save` to `EditableModule`:*

```
privileged aspect EditableModule_Editable {
    public void EditableModule.save() {
        // implemented over here..
    }
}
```

With that in mind, in Eclipse, if you position your cursor on `save` in `Editable` and press `ctrl`+`t`, the Quick Type Hierarchy popup displays `Editable` at the root of the hierarchy tree and a single child `EditableItem`. I would expect to see `EditableModule` there as well.

Can post pom.xml if that would help.

Comment: Sample code for interface, Java class and aspect would be nice for a start. Plus an explanation what exactly you expect to see and what you see instead. You have 7.7k reputation and should know how to ask a question here.

Comment: @kriegaex you're absolutely right -- got a bit lazy there. updated now

Comment: Okay, I see clearer now. Well, that might be a little imperfection or shortcoming in AJDT (AspectJ Development Tools). You might want to ask in the [AspectJ users mailing list](https://dev.eclipse.org/mailman/listinfo/aspectj-users) or open a [BugZilla ticket](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=AspectJ) for this issue (component: IDE) and link it to your question here.